# how to create a model corresponding a view in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a view "Employee_Details" in mysql, which is combination of 7 tables like "user", "user_details", "location", "offer_letters", "employee_details", "client" etc. It showing all details of a user.
I am accessing all values with the help of **hr_controller.rb** with **sqlconnection.rb** file. **sqlconnection.rb** file create in model folder and it's contain all sql connection.
**But I want to create a model for Employee_Details. Can i access all information of Employee_Details view, with the help of new model** After that I will export all information into excel file

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  putting a model on top of a view is the same as a "regular" table.  You still must abide by the restrictions of working with a 'view' i.e.  no updates.

ActiveRecord will automatically pick up all fields from the view once you declare the class

```
class EmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: This is not working, actually I have a view "EmployeeInformation" in phpmyadmin. I am asking, can we create a model for EmployeeInformation view. If yes so please give me a answer.

Comment: I want to access all value of "EmployeeInformation" view. with the help of generated new model.